# multiple if then conditions in Jmeter

Tags: if-statement, jmeter

How is possible to peform multiple if then checks for the same variable in Jmeter ?I need to implement the following if then conditions in Jmeter:

```
if ${laiks} >=0 and ${laiks} <=85959 then ${OrderTime}=0 
if ${laiks} >=90000 and ${laiks} <=105959 then ${OrderTime}=90000 
if ${laiks} >=110000 and ${laiks} <=125959 then ${OrderTime}=110000 
if ${laiks} >=130000 and ${laiks} <=152959 then ${OrderTime}=130000 
if ${laiks} >=153000 and ${laiks} <=235959 then ${OrderTime}=153000
```

I created 5 IF controllers, each with its own condition, but Jmeter is always assigning last value 153000 to ${OrderTime} variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to create `OrderTime` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) based on `laiks` variable value the easiest way of doing this is going for a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the following [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) code:

```
switch (vars.get('laiks') as int) {
    case 0..85959:
        vars.put('OrderTime', '0')
        break
    case 90000..105959:
        vars.put('OrderTime', '90000')
        break
    //etc
    default:
        vars.put('OrderTime', '-1')
}
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)